# Meaning of "play to" and "f****t"

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

According to Urban Dictionary the other sense of *faggot* means "stupid or a loser"--is that correct? And what's the meaning of "playing to the camera"?

> P1: guy has the mannerisms of a faggot
>
> and not the gay kind of faggot
>
> P2: the way he keeps looking at and playing to the camera
>
> douche chills

The comments are made based on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=x8G4jI3VI8U).

Comment: Calling someone *fag* or *faggot* is a highly offensive term (equivalent to calling someone a homosexual with a derogatory tone), so I sanitized it in your title.

Comment: Official English.SE policy on censoring titles: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/975/do-we-really-need-to-add-nsfw-in-question-titles.

Comment: @Carlo_R. The founders of this site have specifically requested that we self-censor the titles of questions so that offensive language does not show up in summaries and cause that SE site, or SE in general, to be auto-banned by parental nannying software. This is an utterly reasonable request **and requirement.** They have asked us to post our offensive material on a non-SE site if we disagree with their official policy about sanitized titles. It is permissible to discuss offensive language in the bodies, of course, just not in the titles. Sim was merely executing the founders’ stated policy.

Comment: @tchrist - ironic though that on ENGLISH.se we are censoring a word that isn't offensive in (English) English

Comment: @tchrist, I agree the policy is a ***requirement*** but disagree with calling it ***utterly reasonable***.  I think ***utterly unreasonable*** is more accurate.  But while I regard the policy as unreasonable, I also see it as ***pragmatic*** and ***practical***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Playing to the camera' (or, in theatre, to the audience) is a histrionic term: seeking to establish a direct relationship with the spectator through such devices as 'mugging', 'upstaging' and 'indicating' instead of maintaining all relationships  *inside* the scene, with your fellow-actors. There are of course occasions and genres when this is perfectly acceptable; but for your common-or-garden-variety screenplay or stageplay it's a cardinal sin. Beyond the profession (The Profession!), it means trying to make yourself the center of attention.

'Faggot' now appears to be age-graded: most people older than about 30 or 35 would only use 'faggot' or 'gay' to denote a homosexual, but people in their 20s are using both as a generalized terms of contempt - which is very troubling for people of my age.

Comment: I would allow that it is troubling for people of ***any*** age. Or should be.

Comment: Well, it wasn't for my son when he was 18, and it was difficult for him to grasp why it should be. But then it was difficult for my father, who was an English professor, to remember that he couldn't use 'gay' the way he always had.